# slug candidates rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have Job model and Location model in my rails application. I am using postgresql as a database.so i have location_ids as an array field in my Job model for holding locations.  I am using FeriendlyId in my application to make my url friendly. when i go to my job show page i am getting this friendly url

```
http://localhost:3000/jobs/seo-trainee
```

but now i also want to include the locations the job has in my url , something like this

```
http://localhost:3000/jobs/seo-trainee-mumbai-tokyo
```

i know we can use slug_candidates for this purpose. but i dont know how can i achieve this exactly

currently i have this in my Job model

```
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :finders]

 def slug_candidates
  [
    :title,
    [:title, :id]
  ]
 end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a custom method to generate your slug definition, and then tell FriendlyId to use that method.

The documentation gives this example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  friendly_id :name_and_location
  def name_and_location
    "#{name} from #{location}"
  end
end

bob = Person.create! :name => "Bob Smith", :location => "New York City"
bob.friendly_id #=> "bob-smith-from-new-york-city"
```

So in your case, you would use something like this:

```
class SomeClass
  friendly_id :job_name_and_location

  def job_name_and_location
    "#{name} #{locations.map(&:name).join(' ')}"
  end
end
```

I've made a few assumptions:

- Your job model has a `name` attribute (`seo training`)
- Your job model `has_many` locations, each of which have a `name` attribute

We then create a method which defines the non-friendly string which FriendlyId will use to create a slug from. In this case it'll come up with something like `SEO Training Mumbai Tokyo` and use that to create your `seo-training-mumbai-tokyo` slug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```
extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :finders]

 def slug_candidates
   locs = Location.where("id IN(?)", self.location_ids).collect{|l| l.name}.join("-") // here, we find the locations for the current job, then joins the each locations name with a '-' sign
   return self.title+"-"+locs // here, returns the job title with the location names
 end
```

So, if your current Job holds location_ids = [1,2,3]
then from Location table we find the locations with id = 1,2,3. Then join their names.

Comment: You shouldn't really be defining SQL like that in Rails unless you're doing something wildly outside of the scope of what ActiveRecord is capable of. What's wrong with using a standard association?